# Fill missing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns : locationid, geo_loc.
locationid column has missing values.

I want to get the geo_loc value of the missing locationid row,
then search this geo_loc value in geo_loc column and get the loction id.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'locationid':[111, np.nan, 145, np.nan, 189,np.nan, 158, 145],
                     'geo_loc':['G12','K11','B16','G12','B22','B16', 'K11',he l 'B16']})
df
```

[image]

I need the final output like this:

[image]

index 1 of locationid is missing and the corresponding geo_loc value is 'K11'.
I would look this 'K11' in geo_loc column and index 6 has locationid 158. With this value 
I want to fill the missing value in index 1.

I tried these codes and they didnt work.

```
df1['locationid'] = df1.locationid.fillna(df1.groupby('geo_loc')['locationid'].max())
```

```
df1['locationid'] = df1.locationid.fillna(df1.groupby('geo_loc').apply(lambda x: print(list(x.locationid)[0])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original filled by aggregate values `max`:

```
df1['locationid']=df1.locationid.fillna(df1.groupby('geo_loc')['locationid'].transform('max'))
print (df1)
   locationid geo_loc
0       111.0     G12
1       158.0     K11
2       145.0     B16
3       111.0     G12
4       189.0     B22
5       145.0     B16
6       158.0     K11
7       145.0     B16
```

If values are strings is is possible by trick - remove missing values with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) in lambda function, strings are compared lexicographically:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'locationid':[111, np.nan, 145, np.nan, 189,np.nan, 158, 145],
                     'geo_loc':['G12','K11','B16','G12','B22','B16', 'K11', 'B16']})

#sample data strings with missing values
df1['locationid'] = df1['locationid'].dropna().astype(str) + 'a'


df1['locationid']= (df1.groupby('geo_loc')['locationid']
                       .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.dropna().max())))

print (df1)
  locationid geo_loc
0     111.0a     G12
1     158.0a     K11
2     145.0a     B16
3     111.0a     G12
4     189.0a     B22
5     145.0a     B16
6     158.0a     K11
7     145.0a     B16
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @jezrael . QQ : What if I had a string values in locationid column? will 'max' work in that case?

Comment: @AdamIqshan - no, then is returned `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`

Comment: @jezrel what other line of code I can use in such case? Many thanks!

Comment: @AdamIqshan - Added solution for this